# if else else construct

Tags: php, database

I'm not 100% comfortable with a PHP class defined here: [mysqli](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/database/mysqli.php)

I stripped out the guts to shorten it somewhat and get a parse error at runtime.

```
<?php

function query($x) 
{
if ($x > 8) {
    return 'greater than eight!';   
    } else {
    return true;
}
} else {
    exit();
    }
}
print query(7);
```

It's the same construct (I think) as the original, isn't it? Apart from the signature and the body of the  method of course.  I haven't come across an if else else clause before and it somehow doesn't 'feel right' for me at least logically wise. Moreover my code won't compile. Maybe you can set me straight?

Do you have any examples of how it may be used?

Secondly, from the original class - where or how does the $resource variable come into it? In what context would the object get passed a $resource variable?

My client code may be:

```
$db = new MySQLi;
$db->query("SELECT * FROM my_table");
```

but I don't see how $resource comes into play?

Comment: I'm sure there is another if  somewhere in the code (or the first else is really an elseif)... When would the 3rd block be triggered?

Comment: formatting your code, you will be find error in where

Comment: In my opinion, this should have been 2 distinct questions

Comment: That's one weird source code. Are you certain the original works? because it seems to me there's a missing if or elseif... I checked the git source file and that shouldn't be working...

Comment: The git source file has major wtf, probably copied from mysql and then only changed in two places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're trying to do something different but I hope this helps to explains how you can tie three conditions together.

```
function query($x) {
    if ($x > 8) { // If $x is greater than 8
        return 'greater than eight!';   
    } else if ($x < 8) { // If $x is lower than 8
        return true;
    } else {
        return "The number is 8!";
    }
}

print query(7);
```

Comment: As I first thought. And yes, I like some of the code that works correctly.

Comment: Good to hear your problem has been resolved. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a second else construct, it should look like:

```
if($x > 8) {
    // your if(true) code
} else {
    // your if(false) code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a missing if else block which is highlighted with ** here that's y you are getting the parser error as same is the problem with your code

```
<?php
final class MySQLi {
private $mysqli;

public function __construct($hostname, $username, $password, $database) {
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

    if ($this->mysqli->connect_error) {
        trigger_error('Error: Could not make a database link (' . $this->mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $this->mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    $this->mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $this->mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    $this->mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION=utf8");
    $this->mysqli->query("SET SQL_MODE = ''");
}

public function query($sql) {
    $result = $this->mysqli->query($sql);



    if ($this->mysqli->errno) {
    //$mysqli->errno
    }

        if (is_resource($resource)) {
            $i = 0;

            $data = array();

            while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
                $data[$i] = $row;

                $i++;
            }

            $result->close();

            $query = new stdClass();
            $query->row = isset($data[0]) ? $data[0] : array();
            $query->rows = $data;
            $query->num_rows = $result->num_rows;

            unset($data);




            return $query;  
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    ***} else {
        trigger_error('Error: ' . mysql_error($this->link) . '<br />Error No: ' . mysql_errno($this->link) . '<br />' . $sql);
        exit();
    }***
}

public function escape($value) {
    return $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($value);
}

public function countAffected() {
    return $this->mysqli->affected_rows;
}

public function getLastId() {
    return $this->mysqli->insert_id;
}   

public function __destruct() {
    $this->mysqli->close();
}
}
?>
```

Comment: this is the code in the link

Answer (score 0):

There is something missing in your code. If you someone runs your code.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE on line 8

So your function should look like below

```
function query($x) 
{
    if ($x > 8) 
    {
     //runs when $x value is greater than 8
     return 'greater than eight!';   
    } 
    else 
    {
     // if the condition didnt meet, according to my knowledge you should return false here 
     return true;
    }

    exit();
}

print query(7);
```

If you want to have a else if,

```
if (condition)
  {
  code to be executed if condition is true;
  }
else if (condition)
  {
  code to be executed if condition is true;
  }
else
  {
  code to be executed if condition is false;
  }
```

Comment: It was just for my own sanity really. Clearly the original code is faulty - I just needed someone to confirm it really. thanks. Sometimes you have to be foolish to really be smart.